# I need an (ordered) set in which I can quickly retrieve the relative index of a member element

Tags: c++, indexing, set

I need to be able to do:

```
MySet<double> s;
/* some insertions, other ops... */

int idx = s.getElemenetIndex(-15.3);
```

and for idx to have either -1 if -15.3 isn't in the set, or the relative index of -15.3 within the set (i.e. some unique element of the set has `getElemenetIndex()` equal to 0, another -1, ... up to the set size -1). I don't care what the ordering is exactly, just that it exists.

- Can I do this with `std::set()`? I mean, in time complexity O(log(n)) where n = s.size()? I know that its underlying implementation, a red-and-black tree, allows this...
- If not `std::set`, perhaps some other readily-available set class? Or do I need to roll my own?

**Notes:**

- About motivation - When I use this set, I'm actually just going to need the indices. It's too complicated and not very relevant to explain what I'll be doing with them.
- I can "commit to immutability", i.e. you may assume all insertions are made before the first call to `getElementIndex()`.
- Insertions (before the first `getElementIndex()`) must be O(log(n)) amortized; deletions do not need to be supported at all.

Comment: I think std::set does not have indices, only iterators. Does this work for you?

Comment: not getting your relative index scenario

Comment: Given a regular `std::set<>` this isn't going to happen in `O(logN)`. Distance calculation is linear in the standard library iterators unless they are full-fledged random-access-iterators, in which case it is constant. `std::set<>` search-result iterators are bidirectional, but not random-access, so no.

Comment: Sounds a bit like an X-Y problem. Can you elaborate on what you want to use the index for?

Comment: Do you need to add and remove elements quickly? If not, a sorted array/vector would fit the bill.

Comment: To support O(log n) distance you have to decorate each node with subtree size. std::set doesn't do this so you have to make your own set implementation.

Comment: If your data is created once and then doesn't change (as you say), a sorted vector is the best (given below). However, I opened a similar question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69751041/is-there-a-data-structure-like-a-c-std-set-which-also-quickly-returns-the-numb) which is clearly equivalent, but I do need to modify the data. The answer given there, [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree), I think is the best when you do need to modify the data over time. @smossen also says this above.

Answer (score 4):

Given that you don't need to modify the set after initially populating it, use a sorted vector.

- Populate (unsorted) with `push_back`: O(1) amortised per element
- Sort using `std::sort`: O(N*log(N)) total, O(log(N)) amortised per element
- Find iterator using `std::lower_bound`: O(log(N))
- Check for equality, and convert to index using `std::distance`: O(1)

Comment: +1 The only limitation on this is the allowance of duplicates with the presented algorithm. Protecting against that would require integrating `std::lower_bound` into the insertion algorithm, or maintaining a separate "exists" set with duplicate data. I'd probably just `reserve()` the top-end capacity, then use a modified insertion-sort via `std::lower_bound` and `std::rotate`, but either way the performance will be as described here in the end-result. nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
std::set<double> s { 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8 };
auto idx=std::distance(begin(s), s.find(7.7));
```

Find is Logarithmic, and I believe the `std::distance` will be O(N) at worst.

EDIT: of course I advise you to check the result of `find` against `end(s)` first and perhaps wrap the whole thing in a function.

Comment: As you guessed, `std::distance` is O(N) and thus this fails the question's requirements.

Comment: @leemes ah, sorry I completely misread the questioners last sentence.

Comment: You could drop the `std::distance` and say that iterators as the result might better fit the requirement. Maybe the OP is ok with that. That means a simple `std::find` would be the solution.

Comment: Indeed, since your N is my set.size(), this is not O(log(set.size())) like I asked. Please see my edit for a followup...