# Is there a data structure like a C++ std set which also quickly returns the number of elements in a range?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, counting

In a C++ `std::set` (*often implemented using red-black binary search trees*), the elements are automatically sorted, and key lookups and deletions in arbitrary positions take time O(log n) *[amortised, i.e. ignoring reallocations when the size gets too big for the current capacity]*.

In a sorted C++ `std::vector`, lookups are also fast *(actually probably a bit faster than `std::set`)*, but insertions are slow *(since maintaining sortedness takes time O(n))*.

However, sorted C++ `std::vector`s have another property: *they can find the number of elements in a range quickly (in time O(log n))*.

i.e., a sorted C++ `std::vector` can quickly answer: *how many elements lie between given x,y?*

`std::set` can quickly find iterators to the start and end of the range, but gives no clue how many elements are within.

So, **is there a data structure** that allows all the speed of a C++ `std::set` (fast lookups and deletions), but also allows fast computation of the **number of elements in a given range?**

*(By fast, I mean time O(log n), or maybe a polynomial in log n, or maybe even sqrt(n). Just as long as it's faster than O(n), since O(n) is almost the same as the trivial O(n log n) to search through everything).*

*(If not possible, even an estimate of the number to within a fixed factor would be useful. For integers a trivial upper bound is y-x+1, but how to get a lower bound? For arbitrary objects with an ordering there's no such estimate).*

**EDIT: I have just seen the**
[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708036/i-need-an-ordered-set-in-which-i-can-quickly-retrieve-the-relative-index-of-a), which essentially asks whether one can compute *the number of preceding elements*. (*Sorry, my fault for not seeing it before*). This is clearly trivially equivalent to this question (*to get the number in a range, just compute the start/end elements and subtract, etc.*)

However, that question also allows the data to be computed once and then be fixed, unlike here, so that question *(and the sorted vector answer)* isn't actually a duplicate of this one.

Comment: `"but gives no clue how many elements are within"`. You could use `std::distance` on the iterators returned by `std::set::lower_bound` / `std::set::upper_bound` but that would be O(distance) for `std::set`.

Comment: [Order statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree)

Comment: @Staz `std::distance` will increment iterators, and incrementing a tree iterator does not take constant time.

Comment: What @molbdnilo said.

Comment: @ChrisD [std::set::iterator is LegacyBidirectionalIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) and std::distance of LegacyBidirectionalIterator is Linear, see [std::distance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)

Comment: It is unclear what the discussion is. Incrementing a std::set::iterator varies in time, but the *average* is constant time, and thus distance becomes linear. It may have been possible to make a faster distance-specialization, but that doesn't exist.

Comment: What's the maximum range you are interested in supporting?

Comment: You said,  "sorted C++ std::vectors have another property: they can find the number of elements in a range quickly (in time O(log n))". I challenge that. They can find the number of elements in O(1) for standard vector. It is enough to use std::distance to subtract the iterators to find the number of elements in a range.

Comment: Also std::deque can be used to improve insertion time. It will move existing elements towards the front/rear depending on where the insertion point. Therefore the maximum that will move  is N/2 elements not N for a vector.

Comment: @SJHowe Yes, but I think we are both right (although talking about different things). You are referring to the time when given the actual endpoints (elements x,y within the vector, and their indices, or iterators), but I was referring to the time when given only lower, upper bounds A,B which might not actually be in the vector.

Comment: (And even given an element x which IS in the sorted vector, it still takes logarithmic time to find its index (or iterator, equivalently). I suppose it's my fault for saying "given range" without being more precise.

Comment: @dyungwang I meant what he/she said about order statistic trees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data structure you're looking for is an [Order Statistic Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree)

It's typically implemented as a binary search tree in which each node additionally stores the size of its subtree.

Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure the STL doesn't provide one.

Answer (score 2):

All data structures have their pros and cons, the reason why the standard library  offers a bunch of containers.

And the rule is that there is often a balance between quickness of modifications and quickness of data extraction. Here you would like to easily access the number of elements in a range. A possibility in a tree based structure would be to cache in each node the number of elements of its  subtree. That would add an average log(N) operations (the height of the tree) on each insertion or deletion, but would highly speedup the computation of the number of elements in a range. Unfortunately, few classes from the C++ standard library are tailored for derivation (and AFAIK `std::set` is not) so you will have to implement your tree from scratch.

Comment: Sorry I can't accept two answers! I accepted the other answer, the same as this one, because it gives the standard name (order statistic tree)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for `LinkedHashSet` alternate for `C++` `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html`.

Comment: Please explain how that would help.

Comment: Misunderstood the question, edited it.